# Need help creating a Jenkins pipeline script to automatically re-submit job upon encountering specific failures in Python code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

## What are the details of your problem?

I am working on a Jenkins pipeline script that runs a Python code as part of a job. However, I need to implement a mechanism that **automatically re-submits** the job if a specific failure/exception is encountered during the execution of the Python code **after sometime** [This is important because say my Python code is calling an external API and its is currently down and we received an `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`, I want to give sometime say 3 to 5 mins. before submitting the next job] without holding up the node resources, but I'm unsure how to handle the re-submission process upon encountering the specific failure condition.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to modify my Jenkins pipeline script to achieve this behavior. Thank you in advance!

Here's the jenkins pipeline code:

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'test' }

    options {
        timeout(time: "${env.TIMEOUT}", unit: 'MINUTES')
    }

    stages {

        stage('Set Build Name') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (env.AUTHOR && env.HEAD_SHA){
                        currentBuild.description = """
                                                    <p><b><a href=${env.PR_URL}>PR_URL</a></p></b>
                                                    <p><b>BaseBranch:${env.BASE_BRANCH}</p></b>
                                                    """
                        currentBuild.displayName = "${env.AUTHOR}-${env.HEAD_SHA[0..6]}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run script') {
            steps {
                script{

                    def command = "#!/usr/bin/bash\nset +xe"

                    command += """\nexport PYTHONPATH="${WORKSPACE}/bin:${WORKSPACE}:${WORKSPACE}/.."
                                source /virtual/python/location/activate
                                python -u ${WORKSPACE}/bin/${JOB}.py
                                """
                    sh script: command
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {

        failure {
            mail to: "${env.ERROR_SUBSCRIBERS}",
            subject: "Failed pipeline: ${env.JOB_NAME}",
            body: "${currentBuild.absoluteUrl}"
        }

        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.log', allowEmptyArchive: true
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.diff', allowEmptyArchive: true
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'result.json', allowEmptyArchive: true
            sh script: 'rm -f *.log *.diff result.json', returnStatus: true
        }
    }
}
```

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I have tried multiple ways and they are as follows:

1. With retry() option -

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'test' }

    options {
        timeout(time: "${env.TIMEOUT}", unit: 'MINUTES')
    }

    stages {

        stage('Set Build Name') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (env.AUTHOR && env.HEAD_SHA){
                        currentBuild.description = """
                                                    <p><b><a href=${env.PR_URL}>PR_URL</a></p></b>
                                                    <p><b>BaseBranch:${env.BASE_BRANCH}</p></b>
                                                    """
                        currentBuild.displayName = "${env.AUTHOR}-${env.HEAD_SHA[0..6]}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run script') {
            steps {

                retry (5) {
                    script{

                        def retryDelayMinutes = 2
                        def attempt = 0
                        def command = "#!/usr/bin/bash\nset +xe"

                        command += """\nexport PYTHONPATH="${WORKSPACE}/bin:${WORKSPACE}:${WORKSPACE}/.."
                                    source /virtual/python/location/activate
                                    python -u ${WORKSPACE}/bin/${JOB}.py
                                    """
                        def result = sh script: command, returnStatus: true

                        if (result != 0) {
                            if (attempt < maxAttempts) {
                                echo "Build attempt $attempt failed, retrying in $retryDelayMinutes minute(s)..."
                                attempt += 1
                                sleep retryDelayMinutes * 60
                            } else {
                                error("Build failed after 5 attempts")
                            }
                        } else {
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {

        failure {
            mail to: "${env.ERROR_SUBSCRIBERS}",
            subject: "Failed pipeline: ${env.JOB_NAME}",
            body: "${currentBuild.absoluteUrl}"
        }

        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.log', allowEmptyArchive: true
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.diff', allowEmptyArchive: true
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'result.json', allowEmptyArchive: true
            sh script: 'rm -f *.log *.diff result.json', returnStatus: true
        }
    }
}
```

but this one holds up the node resources the entire time it's sleeping (which I understand) but I don't want to hold up the node as it can be used by other jobs in the queue.

2. Using the build option -

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'test' }

    options {
        timeout(time: "${env.TIMEOUT}", unit: 'MINUTES')
    }

    stages {

        stage('Set Build Name') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (env.AUTHOR && env.HEAD_SHA){
                        currentBuild.description = """
                                                    <p><b><a href=${env.PR_URL}>PR_URL</a></p></b>
                                                    <p><b>BaseBranch:${env.BASE_BRANCH}</p></b>
                                                    """
                        currentBuild.displayName = "${env.AUTHOR}-${env.HEAD_SHA[0..6]}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run script') {
            steps {

                retry (5) {
                    script{

                        def command = "#!/usr/bin/bash\nset +xe"

                        command += """\nexport PYTHONPATH="${WORKSPACE}/bin:${WORKSPACE}:${WORKSPACE}/.."
                                    source /virtual/python/location/activate
                                    python -u ${WORKSPACE}/bin/${JOB}.py
                                    """
                        catchError {
                            sh script: command
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {

        failure {
            mail to: "${env.ERROR_SUBSCRIBERS}",
            subject: "Failed pipeline: ${env.JOB_NAME}",
            body: "${currentBuild.absoluteUrl}"

            script {
                while (retryCount < maxRetries) {

                    retryCount++

                    def paramsMap = [:]
                    def parametersAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(ParametersAction)
                    if (parametersAction != null) {
                        parametersAction.parameters.each { param ->
                            paramsMap[param.name] = param.value.toString()
                        }
                    }

                    // Re-run the job
                    build job: "${env.JOB_NAME}", parameters: paramsMap, propagate: false, wait: false
                }
            }

        }

        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.log', allowEmptyArchive: true
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.diff', allowEmptyArchive: true
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'result.json', allowEmptyArchive: true
            sh script: 'rm -f *.log *.diff result.json', returnStatus: true
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried with the above pipeline, it gives me an error like:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of interface java.util.List
```

3. Using naginator plugin within the pipeline code, but that also didn't work

**PS: We are using Jenkins Enterprise version**

Comment: The use case is pretty straightforward. We have a jenkins pipeline/job that gets trigger via URL, with parameters to the pipeline/job. 
The main goal of the pipeline is run a python script that might trigger an external service or build a wait and report success/failure. 
When that external service is down or faces an infrastructure failure, we want to be able to write the Jenkins pipeline script in such a way that it automatically retries N times every 5-10 minutes, without holding the agent/node during that time, so that other jobs can run